# Remove SSH identities permanently from ssh agent

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to clear all of my identities on ssh-add.

I tried to clear all the keys using `ssh-add -D` and `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`.

Whenever I restart the terminal and I try listing identities using `ssh-add -l`, all the identities are listed again.

May I know why? and how can I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a new call to `ssh-add` in your shell startup scripts, that reloads the keys into the agent. Try looking in ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc.

Comment: If that's the case, the keys aren't password protected and clearing them from the agent won't change much of anything. Still, a valid answer though :)